# Loop results based on category but only show category once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has 2 columns:

```
Product
Title
```

I'm doing:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product
```

I want to loop all the results of Title but only show Product once per grouping:

```
Product
--Title
--Title
--Title

Product
--Title
--Title
--Title
```

I'm doing a regular do while loop and of course it's showing the Product column for each row. I know I've done this before but can't for the life of me remember! Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can make a array of your results. The key will be the product and the value will be title. After having all your data in your array you could use a foreach loop to show all your results

Comment: or you can use group by in your query. SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product group by product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already ordering your result by product, you could do something like this:

```
$currentProduct = null;

foreach($products as $product) {

    if ($currentProduct != $product['product']) {
        // We got a new product. Show it with some fancy html
        // Then store it in $currentProduct for the next iteration 
        $currentProduct = $product['product'];
    }

    // Show the title with some fancy html
}
```

If you want to use your existing `do while`-loop instead, it's the same.